# django-mptt: .move_to is not working in test runner

Tags: django, unit-testing, move, mptt

the .move_to() method is not working for me. I've looked at other posts an people recommend saving the instance, as well as re-loading the node instances. But none of these solutions work in this test case. I also tried to do ._tree_manager.rebuild(), which doesn't work either. My test code below:

```
def test_reorder_pages(self):
    p = Page.objects.get(slug='page-1')
    p2 = Page.objects.get(slug='page-2')

    self.assertEqual(1, p.lft)
    self.assertEqual(3, p2.lft)

    p2.move_to(p, 'left')

    p = Page.objects.get(slug='page-1')
    p2 = Page.objects.get(slug='page-2')

    ## Values should now be reversed
    self.assertEqual(3, p.lft)
    self.assertEqual(1, p2.lft)
```

Basically what I'm expecting to happen is that page-2 is placed 'before' ( to the left of...) page-1. But the last two asserts fail. Also I checked all the other values (lft, rght, level, tree_id), and *none* of them changed.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** After suggestion by mossplix, I tried Page.tree.rebuild() again. This still doesn't work, but I did notice a strange behaviour.
Before the move_to() these tests would pass:

```
    self.assertEqual(0, p.level)
    self.assertEqual(1, p.lft)
    self.assertEqual(2, p.rght)
    self.assertEqual(1, p.tree_id)

    self.assertEqual(0, p2.level)
    self.assertEqual(3, p2.lft)
    self.assertEqual(4, p2.rght)
    self.assertEqual(1, p.tree_id)
```

After the **move_to()** and **rebuild()** what I'm expecting is this:

```
    self.assertEqual(0, np.level)
    self.assertEqual(3, np.lft)
    self.assertEqual(4, np.rght)
    self.assertEqual(1, p.tree_id)

    self.assertEqual(0, np2.level)
    self.assertEqual(1, np2.lft)
    self.assertEqual(2, np2.rght)
    self.assertEqual(1, p.tree_id)
```

The tests above fail however, and on closer inspection, both pages now have identical values for all those attributes (lft, rght, level, tree_id). Surely this is wrong since that would imply that they occupy the exact same position in the tree?

**Latest Update:**
Seems like using runserver, the moves works perfectly. The issues I'm having seems to be related to the testing framework. I've tried to use TransactionTestCase but this didn't solve the issue either. Updated title to reflect that it's related to tests.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to explicitly call

```
Page.tree.rebuild()
```

after moving the nodes

Comment: I've tried this before, and it didn't work. after your suggestion, I tried again. Still doesn't work but I have noticed something strange.

It's changing _both_ pages so that they have identical values for lft, rght, level, tree_id.

Comment: Edited my original post to reflect the strange behaviour.